# Is it possible to change the debugging shortcut keys in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea

I have spent s lot of my time in VS, and have recently started working in IDEA. the debugging shortcuts in VS and IDEA differ. For instance Idea use F7 for stepping in, whereas VS uses F11.

I am looking for the ability to change the debugging shortcuts in IDEA. I did some research and found   [keymaps](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html). but my brief research shows that keymaps lets you change editor shortcuts, and not debugging shortcuts. Or is my initial assessment about keymap wrong and we can use it for configuring debugging shortcut? if not keymap, is there another way to change the IDEA shortcuts?

Comment: Keymap changes all shortcuts, debugger is also affected, accept the answer from @sidoh, it's correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can edit the relevant shortcuts under Keymap > Main menu > Run

Comment: i figure you can change the editor shortcuts and not the debugger. THat's the reason why I asked this question

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question -- these *do* change the shortcuts for the debugger. Changing "Step Over" from F8 to F11 will do exactly what you'd expect when using the debugger...

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to the Tools field in the menu bar
2. Go select the Options... option in the drop down menu
3. Select Environment
4. Select Keyboard
5. In the "Show Commands Containing" textbox type in the action you are trying to achieve
      e.x. "Debug.Start"
6. Select the "Press Shortcut Keys" textbox and press the keyboard config you would prefer
7. Click Assign
8. Done

Answer (score 3):

You can add plugins for VS keymaps.

1. Go to `File->Settings->Plugins` and search for keymaps. I used the VSCode one.
   [image]
2. Go to `File->Settings->Keymaps` and select it from the list
   [image]
3. Done!

[image]

[image]